# How do I return data from website using ImportXML into separate columns Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

0

I'm using ImportXML in a Google Spreadsheet to input the population demographics from the website https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html. I'd like to extract the population, square miles, and people per square mile into a three-column display of the results.

Currently, I'm doing this by limiting to only these three rows:

=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html", "//div[contains(@class,'c-num')]")),"select * limit 4",-1)

But the output comes out like

N population
N square miles
N people per square mile
and I want it to look like

Population   Square Miles     People Per Square Mile
N               N                      N
Is there a way for me to create this display? (excluded the headers so I can drag down this function in my spreadsheet)

So it would look as such:
N               N                      N

I have this function:

=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML("https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html", "//div[contains(@class,'c-num')]")),"select Col2,Col1 limit 4",-1))

Which gives me this view:
Population   Square Miles     People Per Square Mile
N               N                      N

But I just need the values, not the headers

Answer (score 0):

if its the N N N style, you can try:

`=LAMBDA(ax,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(INDEX(ax,,1),REGEXMATCH(INDEX(ax,,2),"Population|Square"))))(IMPORTXML("https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html", "//div[contains(@class,'c-num')]"))`

[image]

for a single N value you can also use:

`=QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html", "//div[contains(@class,'c-num')]"),"Select Col1 Where Col2='Population'")`

**the formula is hardcoded to ***Population*** here; you may change it to
***Square Miles*** OR ***People Per Square Mile***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.socialexplorer.com/profiles/essential-report/zcta5-48105.html", 
 "//div[contains(@class,'c-num')]"),
 "select Col1 limit 4",-1))
```

[image]